# Has Kim Davis been divorced three times?

Tags: united-states, politics, religion

This [CNN article](http://www.cnn.com/2015/09/02/politics/kentucky-same-sex-marriage-kim-davis-gay-marriage/) claims that [Kim Davis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kim_Davis_(county_clerk)) has been divorced three times.

> The Kentucky county clerk who has refused to issue same-sex marriage licenses for religious reasons despite a Supreme Court ruling has been divorced three times, according to court documents.

It seems like it would get more play in the media if it were really true. Is it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Quoting [Snopes](http://m.snopes.com/kim-davis-married-four-times/#RU0ZL3kZsyec6EGb.99) first published information on 9 July 2015 regarding Kim Davis marital history who in turn refer to Associate Press details as follows,

"Court records detail Kim Davis’ turbulent marital history:

**She has been married to her current husband twice, with a divorce and another husband in between.**

1. She married her first husband, Dwain Wallace, when she was 18, and divorced him in 1994. She acknowledged in a 2008 divorce filing having had two children in 1994 while she was not married.
2. In 1996, at age 30, she married Joe Davis for the first time. They divorced in 2006.
3. The next year, at 40 years old, Davis wed Thomas McIntryre, though their marriage lasted less than a year.
4. She re-married Joe Davis in 2009."